# Is Pex4Fun Broken?

Tags: pex

No matter which puzzle I load in Chrome or Internet Explorer, the "Ask Pex!" button results in some processing followed by "Done." with no results displayed.

As an example, this (http://pex4fun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&sample=ChallengeCaesarCypher) puzzle results in http://snag.gy/Y0LlS.jpg

Previous experience and the video introduction both suggest that I should see a table below the Ask Pex! button.

Comment: I am getting the same results (none).

Comment: The Pex4Fun Windows Phone app says, "Connection failed. Oops, we could not connect to pex4fun. Please connect to the internet and try again." Does not bode well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking if a 3rd party web site is broken

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately the developers of Pex4Fun do not offer any other lines of communication besides StackOverflow Q&A that I could find.  No forums, no contact page, no email address, etc.

Comment: This post on their forums is the last post (everything is locked) stating that they are moving over to Stack Overflow for all interactions.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca65c55b-93cc-492d-b4f6-4f9a448198c2/pex-forums-shifting-to-httpstackoverflowcomquestionstaggedpex?forum=pex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be back up now.  It is unfortunate that Pex4Fun does all support through StackOverflow yet questions like this are against StackOverflow's guidelines (and not appropriate for Q&A since it is a transient state).

Comment: Yes, and as of today, things are broken such that going to pex4fun.com just redirects back to a generic page on the MS site, and the "learn" link is broken.